# How can I retrieve the image which is stored in bytea column of a pg_toast schema?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have a table called `photo`, that contains 3 columns

- chunk_id oid
- chunk_sq int
- chunk_data bytea

How can I see the stored image?

The (bytea) type column contains data like

```
'034\350sec\302\340s\221\\030seq\301\037\022\034seq`uence!V!\364s\030ett\241\376\001\310sho\214rt\224\204\002Tize\001\240\370sloDR#\024\002\020\023\273\003\240\360ourc\324\.................'

select * from pg_toast.photo
```

Answer (score 5):

Certain graphical DB clients will show you the image when going to the table data view.  In plain query output (for example in `psql`), though, you cannot expect images to appear.  Otherwise, you have to 'decode' the `bytea`.

Here is an example solution (written in PHP) on [gis.stackexchange.com](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/32588):

```
$conn = pg_connect("...");
$res = pg_query($conn, "SELECT chunk_data AS photo FROM photo WHERE ...");
$raw = pg_fetch_result($res, 'photo');
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
echo pg_unescape_bytea($raw);
```

**Note:**

`pg_toast` is not usually a schema you query directly from.  What is stored there has a 'parent' table, do your queries against it instead.  Then you can possibly use sane column names in your queries, and so on.